# Why Is Python Loop Not Looping Back To Question

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, user-defined-functions, break

I'm trying to create a loop that will close when the user types a specific question. Within my code, I want the program to close when the user types "Rocket". If the user does not type Rocket, then I want to program to loop back to the original question.

Here is my code:

```
def loop():

    while True:
        close = input("Type 'Rocket' to close the graphical window: ")
        if close != "Rocket":
            break
        else:
            win.close()
            sys.close()

loop()
```

Answer (score 1):

`break` jumps to the point after the innermost iteration loop (`for`, `while`, NOT `if`). If you want to jump to the next iteration (and stay in the loop), use `continue`. If you want to do nothing (and your particular loop will just go to the next iteration), use `pass`.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick by using continue